# Problem to add "," in my windows forms calculator (c#)

Tags: c#, .net, calculator

I am just trying to create a calculator with windows forms on visula studio (c#) everythings works great but when I tried to add the comma. I don't have the correct result.
for example if i try to make: 7.5 -4.5 = I've got the answer 30.

Can you help me please i am new in c# I really want to learn this language.

this is the part:

```
    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double fn;
        double sn;
        double r=0;
        //----------------------------------------------------------------
        double.TryParse(label_firstNun.Text, out fn);
        double.TryParse(label1.Text, out sn);
        //------------------------------------
        if (label_Operator.Text=="+")
        {
            r = fn + sn;
        }
        //-----------------------------------
        if (label_Operator.Text == "-")
        {
            r = fn - sn;
        }
        //-----------------------------------
        if (label_Operator.Text == "*")
        {
            r = fn * sn;
        }
        //-----------------------------------
        if (label_Operator.Text == "%")
        {
            r = fn / sn;
        }
        //-----------------------------------
        label1.Text = r.ToString();
        label_Operator.Text = "";
        label_firstNun.ResetText();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.label1.Text = this.label1.Text + ".";
    }
}
```

thank you very much for your help.

Comment: You are treating the data as strings. Data and formatting should be separate - store your values in the correct data types and you will have an easier time adding functionality. Calculating the result and displaying the result are two separate operations - I assume the issue is that you want to add a thousands separator? Can you add some detail to your question as to what the actual problem is?

Comment: I had an answer but trigger-happy mods already closed this question. What you need is a **decimal point**, not the character '**.**'. To get the correct decimal point character, use `char a = Convert.ToChar(Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator);`

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like your locale doesn't use `.` as a decimal separator. Either use the correct decimal separator for your culture, or use another culture for parsing the numbers (e.g. `double.TryParse(label_firstNun.Text, NumberStyles.Number, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out fn)`).